# Converting HashMap to ArrayList

Tags: java, generics, collections

I just want to move the transitionHash map values into the cardholderDataRecords arraylist.

```
HashMap<String,ExceptionLifeCycleDataBean> transitionHash = new HashMap<String,ExceptionLifeCycleDataBean>();

ArrayList<ExceptionLifeCycleDataBean> cardholderDataRecords = new ArrayList<ExceptionLifeCycleDataBean>();
```

i am doing as

```
cardholderDataRecords.add((ExceptionLifeCycleDataBean) transitionHash.values());
```

It's throwing

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap$Values cannot be cast to com.reportss.bean.ExceptionLifeCycleDataBean
```

Answer (score 130, accepted):

You're trying to cast *the collection of values* to a single `ExceptionLifeCycleDataBean`.

You can very easily get the list though:

```
List<ExceptionLifeCycleDataBean> beans =
    new ArrayList<ExceptionLifeCycleDataBean>(transitionHash.values());
```

Or to add to an existing collection, with:

```
cardholderDataRecords.addAll(transitionHash.values());
```

No casts necessary.

Comment: I successfully converted from HashMap to ArrayList using addAll. But i can't loop the new arraylist using :
for (ExceptionLifeCycleDataBean bean : cardholderDataRecords) 
can it be done ?

Comment: @user2396640 I have no idea what you mean by that. Maybe you should ask a new question with details.

Answer (score -3):

Converting Data HashSet to Array List

```
ArrayList<ExceptionLifeCycleDataBean> cardholderDataRecords = new ArrayList<ExceptionLifeCycleDataBean>(transitionHash);
```

Same Way, You can convert ArrayList to Hashmap.